# Header inclusion error when using C++ for Linux in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

I have created C++ console program targeting Linux from Visual Studio. I have virtual machine that is running Ubuntu. The goal over here is test out the working of Visual Studio for Linux and then create Shared Items project which can be used for Linux as well as Windows.

The program is simple Hello World program where I am trying to include header files provided by vendor. I am following the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?source=recommendations&view=msvc-170) and over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/create-a-new-linux-project?view=msvc-170). Everything works fine and it prints Hello World in Linux terminal but as soon as I try to include other headers it does not compile. It does not show red lines under the #include  but when I run the program in debug mode it gives no such file or directory error. Also, how can I link libraries(.so) file in Visual Studio. Do I follow the same procedure that is used for linking .lib files?

As mentioned it is simple code:

[image]

Comment: Where is the pylon library installed? Have you configured visual studio to use that location? Please don't post images of code and error messages, paste the text into the question

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Hey AlanBirtles, thanks for the comment. Yes, Visual Studio is configured to use the headers. That's the reason why I am confused because typically when Visual Studio is not configured you would see red lines underneath the #include statement. I do not see that but it fails to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was the headers were not synchronized with the remote Linux machine. Although, I had the headers on remote machine there needs to be copy of that on local development system. In order to do that, in Visual Studio under
Tools->Options->Cross Platform->Connection Manager->Remote Headers Intellisense, pick your machine IP address on the right hand side under "List of remote header caches" and press Update button.